Firebase Functions have incorrect data when triggered via Unit Tests
I’m trying run unit tests against for my Cloud Functions through the emulator. However, when I call a wrapped onDocumentWritten function in my unit test, it never receives the proper input data - the value for event.data.after.data() is always the default placeholder { aString: 'foo', anObject: { a: 'qux', b: 'faz' }, aNumber: 7 }.
Any idea why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?
The file for my test is as follows (with <projectId> stubbed out for my testing project id:
import 'jest';

import * as crypto from 'node:crypto'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export function generateTempId() {
    return 'tmp-' + crypto.randomUUID()
}

process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8080'

const app = admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: '<project-id>',
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
})

const db = app.firestore()

const testEnv = require("firebase-functions-test")({
    databaseURL: 'https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: '<project-id>.appspot.com',
    projectId: '<project-id>',
})


const {myOnWriteTrigger} = require("../src/db.ts")

describe("Item Editing", () => {
    let wrapped;

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapped = testEnv.wrap(myOnWriteTrigger)
    })

    test("Write Item", async () => {

        const path = `items/${generateTempId()}`
        const data = {name: "MyTest"}
        
        const s = await db.doc(path).set(data)
        const after = await wrapped(s)

        console.log(after.data())
    })
})

For myOnWriteTrigger:
export const myOnWriteTrigger = onDocumentWritten("items/{itemid}", async (event) => {
    //this will print "{ aString: 'foo', anObject: { a: 'qux', b: 'faz' }, aNumber: 7 }"
    console.log(event.data.after.data())
    if (event.data?.after?.data() == null) {
        console.log("after is null")
        return
    }
    const afterData = event.data.after.data()
    if (afterData.name.includes("My")) {
        const newName = afterData.name.replace("My", "")
        await event.data.after.ref.update({name: newName})
    }
    return  
})

Also note that it still occurs if I give the wrapped function a change from the testEnv:
const beforeSnap = testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({name:'blah'}, path)
const afterSnap = testEnv.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, path)
const change = testEnv.makeChange(beforeSnap, afterSnap)
const after = await wrapped(change)


Please edit the question to show the complete code of the test that doesn't work the way you expect.  What you have now seems lacking, and we can't tell what you might have done wrong.  Also bear in mind that there is a proper framework for testing Cloud Functions with the Firebase SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing

I've edited it to add the full contents of my test code

wrapped doesn't ever get defined in the code you show now.  Seems to me the code would fail on calling a undefined function.

Just edited it to fix that - the same issue still occurs

You also haven't shown myOnWriteTrigger.  We have no idea what it's suppose to do.  You really need to make sure you're showing a complete minimal reproducible example of code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy what you have, run it for ourselves, and reproduce the same result.

Added a sample for myOnWriteTrigger. Let me know if there's something else needed to reproduce

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
